# Can't save css file

Tags: c#, asp.net, umbraco

When i try to save my css files in umbraco client.
I can't and i got a 404 error with a weird url.
I thought there is a problem with folder permission but i can't find something good to change folder permission. (not before or during installation)

[image]

Someone got the same issue?
Thanks already

It worked before but we did an update because we got an issue with version of package nugget.

Comment: Down vote without saying something...thank you

Answer (score 0):

Looks like perhaps you're missing a part of Umbraco's core (the `/umbraco` folder that comes with Umbraco installations. `editstylesheet.aspx` is in the `umbraco` folder (you can see that from the file path in the error message).

Answer (score 0):

Hi found this out recently too. It looks like you are running your Umbraco site as an application under a site. That's what I was doing too. I think Umbraco assumes it is running from the root of the site, which I think is the case for most sites. As you say, it does save the file, but it gets confused when trying to redirect you back. I wouldn't worry about it. I just hit the back button and then refresh to see the changes.